# How to do AsyncTask inside AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, image, text, android-asynctask, download

I want to start an AsyncTask inside another AsyncTask.
I'm trying to do this by starting the second AsyncTask in 'onPostExecute' of the first AsyncTask. The result is that the second AsyncTask starts after the first has finished.
How can I solve this?

Thank you

here's the code

```
private class Parse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    Document doc = null;
    Element son = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("MY_URL").get();
            son= doc.body();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        for(CONDITION){
            //MY_CODE

            new DownloadImageTask().execute();

        }
    }
}
```

This is the second AsyncTask

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView image = new ImageView(Events.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    };

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("MY_URL");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: You could do a check outside the AsyncTask itself for AsyncTask.Status FINISHED before starting the other AsyncTask. Or(as well as) use a callback listener that you have set inside this AsyncTask outside the AsyncTask.  I wouldn't go about embedding AsyncTasks inside each other.

Comment: why???? dont try to make your code too complicated, after you will not able to handle it!

Comment: or you could doinbackground and call the async...

Answer (score 1):

First, please refer to the oficial documentation to have a best understanding about AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The onPostExecute runs in the main thread, after the background task finishes. This method is designed this way to be used to comunicate with the UI thread to handle the execution.

If you want to run the second AsyncTask with your background code, or just after it started, you have to do this on the doInBackground method.